# Query function, select columns based on criteria from a cell

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I would like to use query function and pull the column based on cell criteria. So something like:

```
=QUERY(Data!A3:U,"select A,B" *select the columns with a header same as cell A1*,1)
```

I've tried to select with *arrayformula* but didn't figure anything out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use FILTER:

```
=Filter(A4:U,{1,1,C3:U3=A1})
```

Comment: Excellent!! That's exactly what I was looking to do. I tried filter but forgot to start criteria on the right column.

Comment: on the same topic, I'm trying also to add a filter criteria in the second column. So filter column 2 value equal to B1

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=FILTER(Data!A3:U; Data!A3:U3=A1)
```